# How do I draw shirt with vertical stripes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fill

I am redrawing the character on the following picture via Illustrator:
[image]

Regarding the stripes on the shirt, I already tried to create it by creating a white and a blue linie and using it as a fill, but this doesn't allow me to adjust the stripes to the shape of the character's body.

So my question is how to professionally create the shirt pattern so that the stripes adjust to the body shape. I am a newbie in Illustrator and would be very happy about a step-by-step explanation...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a pattern fill of the stripes.

Draw a rectangle and fill it with the pattern.

Copy the *shape* of the shirt and paste it **on top** of the pattern filled rectangle.

Choose `Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Top Object` from the menu.

You can then alter the envelope to change how the curvature appears. With the enveloped object selected go to `Object > Envelope Distort > Envelope Options...` and check the `Distort Pattern Fills` option to make the pattern follow the curvature.
You can also use the **Mesh Tool** to add additional control points to the overall shape if needed.

[image]

Comment: incredible answer...